# trouble printing elements from the enum

Tags: java, methods, enums

I need to create a enum of the cities of Indiana containing it's population and also i need help iterating thru all the cities and printing the cities with the population which is what im having trouble with? Any help?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (Indiana cities : Indiana.values()) {
        System.out.println(cities + cities.population());
    }
}

enum Indiana {

    FORTWAYNE(899),
    COLUMBIACITY(200),
    FRANKFORT(555),
    AUBURN(789),
    INDIANAPOLIS(1900);

    private String cities;
    private int population;

    private Indiana(String cities, int population) {
        this.cities = cities;
        this.population = population;

    }

    private int getPopulation() {
        return population;

    }

    private String getCities() {
        return cities;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a quite an abuse of an `enum` in my opinion.  `enum`s should be used to enumerate small fixed-sized sets of choices.  Your problem was better modeled with a list of `City` objects called `indiana`.  If you want to do this for more states, consider defining a `State` class as well.

Comment: no it's only for the cities but i'm having trouble printing the cities and the values of the it

Answer (score 0):

there's no population() method. You called it getPopulation() which is preferred accessor method naming. Also please make the method public as suggested below

Comment: It is also `private`…